# How to add 50 for every number over 4 until 31 in a loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops

Ted is hired for a job, and his employer pays him based on number of days he works in a month.  His employer agrees that Ted’s salary is 3 dollars the first day, 9 dollars the second, 27 dollars the third day and 81 for the fourth day. If he works more than 4 days, his employer agrees to pay 50 dollars per day for each additional day of employment. Create an application that allows the user to select/enter into a textbox the number of days that Ted will work and display his regular pay for the month.

Comment: Kameron joined an internet Q&A site, He/she should read [ask] and take the [tour] before posting and expend some effort on a solution first.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: I have been able to write if-then statements for the days before 4. I am struggling for a simple solution on how to write a code that will add 50 to every number after 4, without writing a code for every number up until 31.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current code, and the exact thing you are struggling with. Currently, it looks like you expect someone to write your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you'll need to do validate that the user entered a valid whole number over 0. To do this, you'll need to attempt to convert the value entered into an Integer using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Once the number has been validated, you'll need to keep a running total of the pay. To do this, simply declare an Integer variable since the pay will never contain a decimal.

After you declare the variable, you'll need to check if the days entered is greater than or equal to 1, 2, 3, and/or 4 and then increase the running total respectively by 3, 9, 27, and 81.

Finally, the last step would be to use a For/Next loop to iterate from 5 to the days entered and increment the running total by 50. If the days entered is less than 5 then it will not execute the code inside of the loop.

Here is a quick example demonstrating these instructions:

```
'Prompt for the number of days to work
Dim days As Integer = 0
Console.Write("Days to Work: ")

'Loop until the user enters a valid number over 0
Do Until Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), days) AndAlso days > 0
    'Display the error and re-prompt
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid whole number over 0.")
    Console.Write("Days to Work: ")
Loop

'Keep a running total
Dim total As Integer = 0

'Use a conditional statement to increment the total by 3, 9, 27, and 81 if the days to work are respectively >= 1, 2, 3, 4
If days >= 1 Then
    total += 3
End If
If days >= 2 Then
    total += 9
End If
If days >= 3 Then
    total += 27
End If
If days >= 4 Then
    total += 81
End If

'Now loop from 5 to the number of days to work, if the upper-bounds is less than 5 then the loop won't execute
For counter As Integer = 5 To days
    'Increment the running total by 50
    total += 50
Next

'Display the running total as a currency
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total.ToString("C"))
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qzvqV0)

Comment: Why use a loop when you can use simple Math? 50 dollars per day for each day after the fifth day - so it's simply `50 * (days-5)`...

Comment: Because the user indicated that they needed to use a loop. My guess is that this is an assignment and it is a requirement.

Comment: "Create an application that allows the user to select/enter into a textbox the number of days that Ted will work and display his regular pay for the month." IMHO, students that would solve this using a loop, should get a lower grade than students that would use simple math to do it.

Comment: I want to thank everybody for answering this post. Zohar was right, I could just use that simple formula I just believed a loop was the only way. I wasn't thinking. Thank you David, you showed me the way as well and appreciate your time.

Comment: @Kameron - If you appreciate David's answer, you should accept it.